# Alien Mathematics

Tags: notation, recreational-mathematics

I'd like to pose the community here a challenge.

It's often supposed that if we encounter intelligent alien life, mathematics will probably be how we start communicating.

We have seen Rosetta-stone-type codebreaking, which depends on assuming some common ideas (e.g. proper nouns are phonetically about the same as in another language), and Enigma-type codebreaking, which depends on our ability to analyse a given mathematical system.

But if aliens landed and immediately offered us a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis, would we recognise it?

As a fun exercise, **invent a new mathematical notation** and see if other people in this community can figure out which axiom/theorem/concept you are demonstrating with it.

Your notation should have an unambiguous (albeit initially secret) specification.

Kudos for

a) expressing a nontrivial axiom/theorem/concept, and

b) inventing a notation which is as dissimilar as possible to anything you'd find in an existing textbook.

Comment: "see if other people ... can figure out which axiom/theorem/concept you are demonstrating with it": this is a great way to write bad mathematics, not good.

Comment: OK, we start with what subject? Pythagoras thm or $ (a+b)^2$ identity, or some logical statement  or what?

Comment: Any subject, it's an open question. The idea is that someone could decipher your notation and say "oh I get it, this proves Pythagoras" or "pfft, too easy, those are just Peano numbers".

Comment: If we try to use math to communicate with aliens, I would expect us to begin by exchanging relatively "trivial" facts until at least one side understood something of the other's notation.

Comment: Interesting idea for a question, although I can see why it was closed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it is worthless to play with symbols without knowing their meaning. For instance writing programs to prove theorems require that one be familiar with the game of meaningless formalism.

From the point of view of philosophy it is especially interesting to try to imagine how one would build an intuition in (him/her/it)-self given a formal system and no clue of its meaning. Would it be necessary that two creatures like two Earthlings or two Martians or two intelligent Machines would build the same intuition or would there be a way to share this intuition among each other.

So, I've taken the freedom to give here an example:

I will use the following undefined words (concepts)  "*pötty*", "*igenyes*", "*közt*" and I will use the language of naive set theory and logic (in English).

**Axiom 1.** There exist at least two *pötty* $A$ and $B$ such that $A\not =B$. (no plural after numbers in that martian language : ( )

**Axiom 2.** If $A\not = B$ are *pötty* then there exists a *pötty* $C$ such that $B$ is *közt* $A$ and  $C$.

**Axiom 3.** If $B$ is *közt* $A$ and $C$ then $A\not=C$.

**Axiom 4.** If $B$ is *közt* $A$ and $C$ then $A$ is not *közt* $B$ and $C$.

**Definition**
An *igenyes* of $A$ and $B$ is the set of those *pötty* for which either $P$ is *közt* $A$ and $B$ or $A$ is *közt* $P$ and $B$ or $B$ is *közt* $A$ and $P$.

**Axiom 5.** If the *pötty* $C \not = D$ and both belong to the *igenyes* of the *pötty* $A$ and $B$ then the *pötty* $A$ belongs to the *igenyes* of the *pötty* $C$ and $D$.

**Axiom 6.** There is a *pötty* $C$ wich does not belong to the *igenyes* of the *pötty* $A$ and $B$.

**Axiom 7.** If $B$ is *közt* $A$ and $P$ and $C$ does not belong to the *igenyes* of the *pötty* $A$ and $B$ and if there exits a *pötty* $F$ which is *közt* $B$ and $C$ then there exists a *pötty* such that it is *közt* $A$ and $C$.

**Theorem** For any pair of *pötty* $A\not =B$ there is a *pötty* $C$ such that $C$ is *közt* $A$ and $B$.

**Proof**
???

Intution ???

If I get enough votes up then I disclose the intuition behind.

Comment: I think I get it (spoiler alert): potty are *points*, kozt means *between*, and the *igenyes* are lines. But it helped that you used normal English to express the logic :) Real aliens would not do this...

Comment: @goblin: You win!

Comment: Why would aliens use symbols like $\neq$ or $=$ ? Those are huge clues into your system....

Comment: @N.S. Don't you see that I used Google translate? The original looked like: kjhkchkbfouov7 vbcorbp1qugfuzizoboboibo. At least a character recognition program gave this blah blah.

Comment: By the way, please don't be tempted to delete this answer in future. This was an interesting and fun exercise....

Comment: @goblin: Köszönöm, Goblin! Ez kedves volt tőled.

Comment: Omg he's an alien :) Wait, hungarian?

Comment: @goblin: I am a Martian (Hungarian) he he!

Comment: The best kind of Martian!

Comment: I highly doubt that any different self given formal system would use similar or identical symbols. And for sure they would not use the same structure for quantifiers and implications: "there exists", "if then", "belongs"... They would probably not even use our logic/truth table structure, why would they? What you posted is exactly our formal system, not a different one....

Comment: @N.S. Please, don't take my answer so seriously. I am a philosopher of the mind and my answer was only an innocent and humble try to challenge people. Goblin, for instance, (who looks like another alien / see his/her/its profile) liked my joke.